# Downloaded a Kindle book despite the payment not going through

Tags: united-states, theft

This is a question out of curiosity only. I have an Amazon account and I use it to buy Kindle books. I have bought multiple books with it.

I have paid for a Kindle book but I didn't have enough money on the card. I downloaded the book via Kindle, but the transaction is pending to my bank.

Now I am reading the book. Am I stealing from Amazon?

Answer (score 1):

If you found the store owner didn't charge you the right price, you'd bring the article and receipt back. I have with a measuring tape I bought from a building supply store. The same principle applies to any purchase, whether it's online or not.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on intent - if you deliberately made the transaction knowing it would bounce back then yes, it would be theft or fraud.  If you did it innocently, then there is no theft or fraud, but there is civil debt (ie an obligation to "make good" - but not a criminal matter)

I disagree somewhat with @TedHarison answer - at least around my part of the world - if a store owner charges you the wrong price - and its too much, then you have recourse  (misrepresentation/false advertising), if it was too cheap, their loss.  I believe this is because prices on the shelf are "An offer to treat".  When they ring the price up at the till its an offer, when you pay its acceptance.  [ For the -1 brigade - please look [here](http://www.cab.org.nz/vat/consumer/bts/Pages/Promisesabouttheprice.aspx) first ]